# Auto increment item (ordinal numbers) in Oracle APEX

Tags: oracle-apex, auto-increment

I want to make my item id auto increment, so that user cannot insert any number. It is for ordinal numbers of inovice items, so there can't be any gaps.

Table:

`TABLE_NAME (id NUMBER GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY( NOCACHE), name VARCHAR2(10), PRIMARY KEY (id));`

Then I created a process with PL/SQL code:

`IF :P27_ID IS NULL THEN`
`SELECT ID.NEXTVAL INTO :P27_ID FROM DUAL;`
`END IF;`

But if I delete an item, his value is lost and next entered item won't have his id.

Comment: Have you tried Google?

Comment: There are plenty of explanations available and this isn't Oracle-specific. Try Googling terms like "gapless database ids" and other variants.

Comment: Is it just for display? Have you considered the row_number() analytical function?

Comment: Mateja, I believe you should split your problem. 1) primary key value - this is meant for data integrity, it should not have any business value. I would keep that as an identity column and allow gaps - who cares. 2) your invoice number. That is a number that should not have any gaps and it should be stored in its own column with a unique constraint (so you don't have duplicates). Check google on possibilities for gapless sequences. Maybe you can do MAX(highest_val + 1) but you always have the risk of dupes if 2 transactions overlap.

Comment: @KoenLostrie Yes, I was thinking about that too.

Comment: I agree with splitting up your primary key and your order id. However, either could have gaps. You'd have to implement strict business processes to prevent it (no rows can ever be deleted, order id is generated at insert time only, etc.). But again, why bother with this stuff. He's a recent order id I got from Apple: MKMSHJ2BJ5 Just do something like that.

Comment: Because it is for ordinal numbers of invoice items. The user can see that, it's important to have right numbers.